# What numbers fill the blanks to satisfy the equation?

Tags: logical-deduction, formation-of-numbers

Complete the grid shown below with the digits 1 to 6 to make the sum correct.

Perform each mathematical operation in the order shown, from left to right, e.g. 1 + 2 x 3 is treated as (1 + 2) x 3 = 9.

Note: there is no ÷ 1, and at no point is a decimal or fraction used.

$$[\;\;\;\;] + [\;\;\;\;] - [\;\;\;\;] * [\;\;\;\;] \div [\;\;\;\;] * [\;\;\;\;] = 50$$

The $[\;\;\;\;]$ are empty spaces and must be filled with numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was just a little slower than Bailey, but to add further detail:

You start by working out that the last number can only be:

> 5,2 or 1: 5 is more likely as it involves a smaller answer to using the other numbers

This makes:

> [ ] + [ ] - [ ] x [ ] ÷ [ ] = 10

You now want a small number to divide by, that isn't 1 - so this should either be 2 or 3 making

> [ ] + [ ] - [ ] x [ ] = 20

Or

> [ ] + [ ] - [ ] x [ ] = 30

With the 4 numbers and 3 sums remaining, it is impossible to make the former and are forced down the latter route to create:

> 4 + 2 - 1 x 6 / 3 x 5 = 50

Comment: I went through the exact same thought process as this - I just so happened to try ÷3 first, which gave me a correct answer and therefore no reason to try ÷2.

Answer (score 8):

I "cheated" and wrote a Python script that used the Johnson-Trotter algorithm to permute the order of the numbers that are plugged into the equation.
My script spits out 6 possible solutions:

> 3 + 6 - 4 x 5 ÷ 1 x 2
>  6 + 3 - 4 x 5 ÷ 1 x 2
>  6 + 3 - 4 x 2 ÷ 1 x 5
>  3 + 6 - 4 x 2 ÷ 1 x 5
>  4 + 2 - 1 x 6 ÷ 3 x 5
>  2 + 4 - 1 x 6 ÷ 3 x 5

Though, given the extra conditions of the puzzle (no ÷1 and never dealing with decimals/fractions), you're left with 2 solutions because addition is commutative.

> 4 + 2 - 1 x 6 ÷ 3 x 5
>  2 + 4 - 1 x 6 ÷ 3 x 5

I'm sure the pen-and-paper method accomplished above is probably more satisfying to perform, though!

---

**Python Source**

Play with the code [here](http://runnable.com/VXdoe9nVYnl16qFW/johnson-trotter-permuter-for-python).

This is just a [Johnson-Trotter](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Combinatorics/JohnsonTrotter.shtml) permutation class I wrote. It uses a `step` function to go to the next permutation. I thought about making an iterator version, but was too lazy =/. It may be a little lengthy, but it can be used to permute any list of objects. I'm sure it could be improved and condensed; I just threw this together for this puzzle =P

jtpermute.py

```
class JohnsonTrotterPermute(object):
    objlist = []   # contains the objects given to the class
    nodelist = []  # contains the JTNode objects that wrap around each given object
    numnodes = 0   # the current number of nodes added (for numbering)
    steps = 1      # the number of iterations generated (number of steps)

    def __init__(self, objlist):
        self.objlist = objlist
        for obj in self.objlist:
            self.nodelist.append(JTNode(self.numnodes, obj))
            self.numnodes += 1

    # returns True if there exists at least one mobile JTNode
    def has_mobile(self):
        for i in range(len(self.nodelist)):
            if self.check_mobility(i):
                return True
        return False

    # returns True if the JTNode at the given index is mobile
    def check_mobility(self, index):
        if index < 0 or index >= len(self.nodelist):
            return False
        if self.nodelist[index].direction == -1: # pointing left
            if index == 0: # on the left edge of list
                return False
            if self.nodelist[index].num > self.nodelist[index - 1].num:
                return True
        if self.nodelist[index].direction == 1:  # pointing right
            if index == len(self.nodelist) - 1:  # on the right edge of list
                return False
            if self.nodelist[index].num > self.nodelist[index + 1].num:
                return True
        return False

    # iterates through the nodes and flips the direction of any node
    # whose .num is larger than the given number
    def flip_larger_than_num(self, num):
        for node in self.nodelist:
            if (node.num > num):
                node.flip()

    # returns the index of the JTNode that has the largest .num value
    # and is mobile
    def get_largest_mobile_index(self):
        index = -1
        largest = -1
        for i in range(len(self.nodelist)):
            if self.nodelist[i].num > largest and self.check_mobility(i):
                largest = self.nodelist[i].num
                index = i
        return index

    # swaps the node at the given index with the node that it's pointing
    # at. Returns True if the swap is successful, False if the swap fails
    # (e.g. the node is pointing left, but it's the left-most node)
    def move_node(self, index):
        node = self.nodelist[index]
        tempnode = None
        if node.direction == -1: # pointed left
            if index == 0: # on left edge of list
                return False
            tempnode = self.nodelist[index]
            self.nodelist[index] = self.nodelist[index - 1]
            self.nodelist[index - 1] = tempnode
            self.flip_larger_than_num(tempnode.num)
        if node.direction == 1: # pointed right
            if index == len(self.nodelist) - 1: # on right edge of list
                return False
            tempnode = self.nodelist[index]
            self.nodelist[index] = self.nodelist[index + 1]
            self.nodelist[index + 1] = tempnode
            self.flip_larger_than_num(tempnode.num)
        return True

    # steps the list order to its next iteration
    def step(self):
        if self.has_mobile():
            largest_mobile = self.get_largest_mobile_index()
            self.move_node(largest_mobile)
            self.steps += 1
            return True
        return False

    # returns the list of items that the user initially provided in the
    # order of the current iteration
    def get_items(self):
        returnlist = []
        for node in self.nodelist:
            returnlist.append(node.obj)
        return returnlist



# a wrapper class for the list items the user will provide
class JTNode(object):
    obj = None      # the actual user-provided list item
    num = -1        # the number of the node
    direction = -1  # pointing direction (-1 -> left, 1 -> right)

    def __init__(self, num, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.num = num

    # flip the direction the node is pointing
    def flip(self):
        self.direction *= -1
```

puzzle.py

```
from jtpermute import *

# computes the puzzle equation on the given list of integers
def do_maths(intlist):
    if len(intlist) < 6:
        return 0
    num = intlist[0]
    num += intlist[1]
    num -= intlist[2]
    num *= intlist[3]
    num /= intlist[4]
    num *= intlist[5]
    return num

# prints the puzzle's function with the numbers plugged in
def print_maths(intlist):
    if len(intlist) < 6:
        return 0
    # a string builder of sorts
    strlist = []
    strlist.append(str(intlist[0]))
    strlist.append(" + ")
    strlist.append(str(intlist[1]))
    strlist.append(" - ")
    strlist.append(str(intlist[2]))
    strlist.append(" * ")
    strlist.append(str(intlist[3]))
    strlist.append(" / ")
    strlist.append(str(intlist[4]))
    strlist.append(" * ")
    strlist.append(str(intlist[5]))
    strlist.append(" = ")
    strlist.append(str(do_maths(intlist)))
    print "".join(strlist)

jtp = JohnsonTrotterPermute([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
# the equivalent of a do-while loop in Python. I wanted to put the
# step function in the loop conditional, but it had to be evaluated
# before the first .step call. When the step function returns False,
# it has reached the end of the permutations
while True:
    if do_maths(jtp.get_items()) == 50:
        print_maths(jtp.get_items())
    if jtp.step() == False:
        break
print "Number of permutations: %d" % jtp.steps
```

Output of puzzle.py

> `3 + 6 - 4 * 5 / 1 * 2 = 50`
>  `6 + 3 - 4 * 5 / 1 * 2 = 50`
>  `6 + 3 - 4 * 2 / 1 * 5 = 50`
>  `3 + 6 - 4 * 2 / 1 * 5 = 50`
>  `4 + 2 - 1 * 6 / 3 * 5 = 50`
>  `2 + 4 - 1 * 6 / 3 * 5 = 50`
>  `Number of permutations: 720`

Comment: Could you please show your Python script?

Answer (score 5):

> [4] + [2] - [1] x [6] ÷ [3] x [5] = 50

Or, a cleaner version:

> ((4 + 2) - 1) x ((6 / 3) x 5) = 50